# How does iPhone app remember me feature works?

Tags: iphone, ios

I developed an iPhone app. User need to log in to update their credentials. I'm using iOS Keychain feature to store the username and password. So, next time user launch the app user will be logged in. I would like to add remember me feature in my app. So, user will have an option to check the remember me or not.

My question is if the user don't want to remember his credentials, when I'm suppose to clear the keychain? How do I know if the app is closing/shutdown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

– applicationWillResignActive:
– applicationDidEnterBackground:

These two methods are called depending on the situation when the app enters background.(sleep button/phone call etc).

You can look it up in the docs.
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIApplicationDelegate

Answer (score -1):

You meed to write the login credentials to application preferences.

(Here is how to read write to iPhone app preference)
http://knol.google.com/k/iphone-sdk-application-preferences#

Also here is how to read default preferences 
http://www.redcodelabs.com/2009/07/read-iphone-preferences/